# Как создать архив папки из скрипта python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Хочу создать архив папки через tar из python. Для этого делаю вот что:

```
import subprocess
folder_path = '/home/path/to/my/folder'
subprocess.run(['tar', '-cf', 'archive_name.tar', folder_path])
```

В принципе, архив создается, но внутри него содержится вся иерархия папок: home -> path -> to -> my -> folder. А как сделать так, чтобы архив содержал только эту папку или, например, то, что лежит в этой папке.

В терминале можно было бы просто перейти для начала в нужную папку, а как так сделать из скрипта не понимаю:

```
cd /home/path/to/my
tar -cf archive_name.tar folder
```

Comment: [shutil.make_archive](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) ? или в скрипте сделайте `folder_path` текущей активной директорией `os.chrdir(folder_path)`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую shutil.make_archive, не знал про него)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir_path = '/home/path/to/my'
dir = 'folder'
subprocess.run(['tar', '-cf', 'archive_name.tar', '-C', dir_path, dir])
```

Параметр `-C` меняет каталог на заданный.
см. [`man tar`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tar&category=1&russian=0) за подробностями.

Comment: На любом языке можно писать на shell. Понятно, что к автору вопроса это относится в первую очередь.

Comment: Создание/распаковка архива — одна из задач, где использование внешней утилиты является неплохим решением... это позволяет грамотному пользователю легко задать параметры под свои нужды, а программисту дать ему такую возможность... Но от записей вида `files=os.popen("ls")read().split()` у меня, как у всех убывает вера в благополучие человечества...